# Convergence of a sequence to its eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Consider that we have a matrix $~~~ M \in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) ~~~$ symmetric, positive definite.
If I set the recurrence relation $$x_{n+1} = 
\frac{Mx_{n}}{\lVert Mx_{n}\rVert}   \phantom{600} x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

I know that under certain assumptions, this series converges to the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue.

I can see nicely that the value converges to an eigenvector, the problem is that is not clear to me why it converges to the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue.

Am I losing any detail here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are the eigenvectors of $M$ and $\lambda_1$ is the largest eigenvalue, then if 
$$
x_0 = a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_k v_k
$$
$x_n$ will be the unit vector in the direction of
$$
a_1\lambda_1^nv_1 + \cdots + a_k\lambda_k^n v_k
$$
which is, in other words, the unit vector in the direction of 
$$
a_1 v_1 + a_2 \left(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right)^n v_2 + \cdots + 
a_k \left(\frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda_1}\right)^nv_k
$$
Perhaps now you can see how things will progress, assuming that $a_1 \neq 0$.